# Finite list induction principle and the tail eliminator

Tags: dependent-types, inductive-datatypes

In Dybjer's *Inductive Families* the author present a method to derive an eliminator/induction principle for every inductive family of types.

In particular for the type of finite lists, namely
$$List' \colon (A \colon set) (n \colon N) set$$
we get the eliminator 
$$\begin{align*}
listrec' \colon &(A \colon set)\\
& (C \colon (a \colon N)(c \colon List'_A n)set) \\
& (e_1 \colon C(0,nil'_A)\\
& (e_2 \colon (b_1  \colon N)(b_2 \colon A)(u \colon List'_A(b_1))(v \colon C(b_1,u))C(s(b_1),cons'_A(b_1,b_2,u)))\\
& (a \colon N) \\
& (c \colon List'_A(a)) \\
& C(a,c)\ .
\end{align*}$$

From what I get from this eliminator we should be able to provide any possible operation using finite lists.

Now my question is

> how do we get the classical *destructor* $$tail \colon (A \colon set)(n \colon N)(List'_A(s(n))) List'_A n$$
>   that from any finite list gets its tail?

I am totally lost on how to approach this problem since the eliminator seems to be able to provide just function defined on the whole family $List'_A(n)$ and not on the sub-family $List'_A(s(n))$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be an answer in the [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/) standard library. Coq calls the type of lists of a given length “vector”. I don't know if the code would be comprehensible though.

Comment: @Gilles I have give a lookbat Coq stdlib, it seems that they use a form of pattern matching not eliminators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am totally lost on how to approach this problem since the eliminator seems to be able to provide just function defined on the whole family List′A(n) and not on the sub-family List′A(s(n)).

The typical trick in this situation is to pick a `C` such that you can pretend you are defining a function on the whole family when, in fact, you're only focusing on the sub-family you care about thanks to equality constraints.

Let me be more concrete:

If you pick `C(n, xs) = (m:N) -> n = s(m) -> List'_A(m)` then you can define a generalised `gtail` by using `listrec'`, and derive `tail` as a corollary.

```
gtail : (A:set) (n:N) (xs : List'_A(n)) -> C(n, xs)
gtail A = listrec' A C
          contradiction -- of type: (m:N) -> 0 = s(m) -> List'_A(m)
          (\ _ _ u _ -> u)

tail : (A:set) (n:N) -> List′A (s(n)) -> List′An
tail A n xs = gtailn A (s(n)) xs n refl
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have doubt, It is not clear to me how you can provide the term contradiction which by its very definition should not exist.

Comment: Contradiction can exist just fine as long as you have large elimination. Cf. https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/inria-00489412/ You're not asked to prove False, you're asked to prove anything given an (absurd) proof of `0 = s(m)`.

Comment: I'm not following, you provide a $0 = s(m)$ which is a constant (or did I miss a lambda lurking around) and should not be derivable (or did I miss something). Anyway I think I got the idea. I just need some time to digest it. Thanks again.

Comment: You don't provide a `0 = s(m)`, you are given one in the nil case.

Comment: I got it, silly me, I had misread the type of contradiction. Perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is just a little modification of the idea proposed in the accepted answer, nevertheless I think it can be of interest to other readers.

Here's a way to build tail

We can consider the predicate
$P \colon (A\colon set)(n \colon N)(l \colon List'_A n)set$ defined (by recursion on natural numbers) as the only type family such that
$$\begin{align*}
P(A,0,l)&= 1\\
P(A, s(n),l) &= List'_A (n)
\end{align*}$$
where $1$ is the unit type with only term $()$.

If we let
$$e_1 = () \colon 1= P(A,0,nil')$$
and 
$$e_2=\lambda n \colon N.\lambda x \colon A.\lambda xs \colon List'_A n. \lambda p \colon P(A,n,xs). xs \colon (n \colon N)(x\colon A)(xs \colon List'_A n)(p \colon P(A,n,xs))\underbrace{List'_A(n)}_{=P(A,s(n),cons'_A(n,x,xs))}$$
we get
$almostTail = (\lambda A \colon set) listrec'(A,P(A),e_1,e_2) \colon (A \colon set)(n \colon N)(l \colon List'_A(n))P(A,n,l)$
which by the reduction principle is such that
$$almostTail(A,s(n),cons'_A(n,x,xs))=e_2(n,x,xs,almostTail(A,n,xs))=xs\ .$$

So we get
$$tail' \colon (A\colon set)(n\colon N)(l \colon List'_A(s(n)))\underbrace{P(A,s(n),l)}_{List'_A(n)}$$
by letting
$$tail'(A,n,l) = almostTile(A,s(n),l)\ .$$

**Note**: the only difference between gallais' example and mine is that instead of adding an hypothesis in the predicate to pass to $listrec'$ I have used a predicate with a *don't care value* for the case $n=0$.

In this case too we basically build a function defined on all the lists, with the desired behaviour in the case of interest (i.e. not empty lists), and then consider the specialized/restricted function for the sub-family of types we are interested in.

Comment: Nice one! We have the same dichotomy in Agda's standard library between e.g. `from-just : (x : Maybe A) → From-just x` which computes the return type and only does something interesting if `x` has the right shape and `to-witness : (m : Maybe P) → Is-just m → P` which uses a constraint to ensure the argument has the right shape to begin with. Both are useful! Link to the module in question: https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.Maybe.Base.html